# How to view all posts (on site, not admin) that are uncategorized?

Tags: posts, categories, archives

I had a horrible problem a long time ago that had me end up importing a backup of most of my posts.

I'm now using WordPress 3.3.2 and I would like to view all of the uncategorized posts from the site view, not in the admin.

I have attempted to use

http://www.southfresh.org/uncategorized

http://www.southfresh.org/category/uncategorized

Both with capitalized and not.

But those come up as bad pages.  Is there any way to view just these posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not 'bad pages' (404), they're empty archives.  Make sure you have published posts in the 'uncategorized' category, since I don't actually see any in the sidebar list.

Comment: I had about 200 in the uncategorized category.  I went through the site one by one to edit.

Comment: Publish a post in the 'uncategorized' category, disable all plugins, and switch to default theme.  It really looks like the archive page is working fine (the 2nd link in your post), it's just not finding any posts.  To me, this points first to a theme issue (perhaps your `archive.php` filters that category).